# Add elements of ArrayList into a 2d Array

Tags: arrays, chess

I am reading a text file and saving its contents into an ArrayList, know I wanna populate an 8x8 array with the contents of the Arraylist. My goal is to read a file with chess pieces, color and position and then check for valid moves. However, I am new to java and unsure how to check the arrayList for these attributes, ie., if it is a white or black piece.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public static void MoveCheck(String answer,ArrayList<String> board){
        String move; 
        if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("pawn")){
            System.out.println("What position do you want to move to?");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            move = scanner.nextLine();
            if(board.contains("white")){ 
                if(move.equalsIgnoreCase("B3")||(move.equalsIgnoreCase("B4"))){
                    System.out.println("Valid move");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Invalid move/Not on the board");
                }
            }
        }

public static void main(String args[]){

        String answer;
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int [][] board = new int[7][7];
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("chess.txt"))){
            while(br.ready()){
                result.add(br.readLine());
            }
        }   catch (Exception e){
            System.out.print("Error occurred while reading.");
        }

       for (String line : result){
            System.out.println(line);
       }

        System.out.println("Select a piece to move");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        answer = scanner.nextLine();

        MoveCheck(answer,result);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [FEN Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation)

You can import the position with the pgn notation

it would look something like this

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1
```

Then you could just read this string from left to right one char at a time to be able to populate your board.

Small cased letter = black piece

Capital cased letter = white piece

/ means next row

number = number of empty squares from the A column until the next piece

w means it is white to move

KQkq means both sides can castle both kingside and queenside

0 1 means it is currently white's first move